# strcmp and void pointer in C

Tags: c, pointers, strcmp

I wrote this simple code for string comparison

```
    #include<stdio.h>

    void strCmp(char *,char *);

    int main() {
        char* str1 = "hello";
        char* str2 = "hello";
        strCmp(str1,str2);
        return 0;
    }
    void strCmp(char *vp1,char *vp2) {
        int r = strcmp(vp1,vp2);
        printf("result %d",r);
    }
```

And then to check what will happen if I pass void*  instead of char*, I rewrote the code like this:

```
    #include<stdio.h>

    void strCmp(void *,void *);

    int main() {
        char* str1 = "hello";
        char* str2 = "hello";
        strCmp(str1,str2);
        return 0;
    }
    void strCmp(void *vp1,void *vp2) {
        int r = strcmp(vp1,vp2);
        printf("result %d",r);
    }
```

The above code gets compiled and works as expected! If I go crazy further and do

```
    #include<stdio.h>

    void strCmp(void **,void **);

    int main() {
        char** str1 = "helloxx";
        char** str2 = "hellox";
        strCmp(str1,str2);
        return 0;
    }
    void strCmp(void **vp1,void **vp2) {
        int r = strcmp(vp1,vp2);
        printf("result %d",r);
    }
```

No failure and the results are fine. I wondered what is the implementation of strcmp and copy pasted the code from https://stackoverflow.com/a/10927187/2304258 as a custom function in my code but it fails with the usual error messages you expect when you use a `void*` without casting.

Can you please explain how the above implementations are working?

Comment: This does not compile in C++. Please do not tag irrelevant languages.

Comment: See the your specific `stdio.h`. It seems `strcmp` has `int(const void*, const void*)` signature there.

Comment: That's why you shouldn't ignore compiler warnings.

Comment: Your third piece of code is illegal. Please invoke your compiler in conforming mode.

Comment: the code does not cleanly compile.  the code is missing: '#include <string.h>'  The last example does not compile due to syntax errors

Comment: It is a very bad programming practice to implement function names that mimic the system functions with the only difference being the capitalization.  However, using some prefix like 'my' works very well and is clear as to what is intended.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two points in your question.

The first is why it actually works. 
The second is whether your program is guaranteed to always work.

The answer to the first point is that it works because `strcmp` simply expects two pointers as parameters. Those pointers are of type `char *`, they are supposed to contain addresses to null terminated sequences of chars (bytes). Your different implementations took such two pointers, then cast them to various types (to `void *` in the first case, `char **` in the second), then cast them back to `char *` and then call the `strcmp`. It works, because in practically all real C implementations, the cast of one pointer type to another does not change the value of the pointer. So it does not matter to which pointer and how many times you cast and recast the pointer. Note that in C++ the situation is different, because the cast often changes the actual address (value of the pointer).

The second point is whether your programs are correct according to the C standard.  In this case the first one is correct, because C standard says that you can always cast any pointer to `void *` and when you cast it back to the original type, you get back the original pointer. However, this is not true for casting to other types, so you are not guaranteed that after casting `char *` to `char **` and back to `char *` you get the original pointer. The C language does not guarantee that your last program will work.

To be more precise, here are two relevant quotes from C99 standard:

> 6.3.2.3 Pointers
>
> 1.) A pointer to void may be converted to or from a pointer to any incomplete or object
>   type. A pointer to any incomplete or object type may be converted to a pointer to void
>   and back again; the result shall compare equal to the original pointer.

...

> 7.) A pointer to an object or incomplete type may be converted to a pointer to a different
>   object or incomplete type. If the resulting pointer is not correctly aligned57) for the
>   pointed-to type, the behavior is undefined. Otherwise, when converted back again, the
>   result shall compare equal to the original pointer. When a pointer to an object is converted to a pointer to a character type, the result points to the lowest addressed byte of
>   the object. Successive increments of the result, up to the size of the object, yield pointers
>   to the remaining bytes of the object.

Answer (score 1):

Well, first of all, you really ought to

```
#include <string.h>
```

Secondly, it's highly recommended that you use strncmp(). Finally, this is really just how C works (which is different from C++). It will do an implicit cast from void* to any other pointer (which is why e.g. malloc() just works). See also [How to interpret section 6.3.2.3 part 7 of the C11 standard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24010608/how-to-interpret-section-6-3-2-3-part-7-of-the-c11-standard) .

As for why the code from libc didn't work for you, I don't know. It certainly worked for me (after I fixed the missing type declaration).

Comment: Note that this code does not use the special rule for conversion from and to `void*`. It just assigns incompatible pointer types to each other, which is warning-worthy.

Answer (score 1):

It works because C almost always assumes that programmers knows what it does.

Even if str1 and str2 are declared as `char**` they actually contain a pointer to `char`

C automatically converts from and to pointer to any type to pointer to `void`

So in the end, you pass `char *` to strcmp and it can do its job.

But when I compiled it I got warnings (even after adding `#include <string.h>` to have a correct declaration for strcmp) :

```
foo.c(7) : warning C4047: 'initialisation' : 'char **' diffère de 'char [8]' dans les niveaux d'indirection
foo.c(8) : warning C4047: 'initialisation' : 'char **' diffère de 'char [7]' dans les niveaux d'indirection
foo.c(13) : warning C4047: 'fonction' : 'const char *' diffère de 'void **' dans les niveaux d'indirection
foo.c(13) : warning C4024: 'strcmp' : types différents pour le paramètre formel et réel 1
foo.c(13) : warning C4047: 'fonction' : 'const char *' diffère de 'void **' dans les niveaux d'indirection
foo.c(13) : warning C4024: 'strcmp' : types différents pour le paramètre formel et réel 2
```

In english it should be more or less:

```
foo.c(7) : warning C4047: 'init' : 'char **' and 'char [8]' have different indexation level
foo.c(8) : warning C4047: 'initialisation' : 'char **' and 'char [7]'  have different indexation level
foo.c(13) : warning C4047: 'function' : 'const char *' and 'void **' have different indexation level
foo.c(13) : warning C4024: 'strcmp' : different types for formal and actual parameter 1
foo.c(13) : warning C4047: 'function' : 'const char *' and  'void **' dhave different indexation level
foo.c(13) : warning C4024: 'strcmp' : different types for formal and actual parameter 2
```

Those warning should not be ignored because they to show real problems in the code.

Comment: in English it would be "function"